# Volume of a cross section

Tags: volume

> Q: A volume sits above the ellipse in the xy-plane  $\frac{x^2}{4} + y^2 = 1$
>   Each x cross section is a square, with side touching the top
>   and bottom of the ellipse. What is the volume?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the previous question you have asked, 
$$
V = \int\limits_{-2}^2 4 - x^2 \ \mathrm{d}x
$$
Explanation: Same as [Volume using cross sections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601093/volume-using-cross-sections/601101#601101)