# How to calculate volume of ellipse rotating around x axel?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

I have equation of ellipse

$4x^{2} +y^{2} = 36$

and i know formula for volume

$v =\pi \int_{a}^{b}y^{2} dx$

but i have trouble with determining the limits which i should use in this formula. How should it be done in this case?

Comment: Please see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601093/volume-using-cross-sections

Comment: From your equation, $x$ can be anywhere in $[-3,3].$ [Then $y^2=36-4x^2$ in the integral.]